# Using conftest.py vs. importing fixtures from dedicate modules

Tags: python, pytest

I have been familiarizing with pytest lately and on how you can use `conftest.py` to define fixtures that are automatically discovered and imported within my tests. It is pretty clear to me how `conftest.py` works and how it can be used, but I'm not sure about why this is considered a best practice in some basic scenarios.

Let's say my tests are structured in this way:

```
tests/
--test_a.py
--test_b.py
```

The best practice, as suggested by the documentation and various articles about pytest around the web, would be to define a `conftest.py` file with some fixtures to be used in both `test_a.py` and `test_b.py`. In order to better organize my fixtures, I might have the need of splitting them into separate files in a semantically meaningful way, ex. `db_session_fixtures.py`, `dataframe_fixtures.py`, and then import them as plugins in `conftest.py`.

```
tests/
--test_a.py
--test_b.py
--conftest.py
--db_session_fixtures.py
--dataframe_fixtures.py
```

In `conftest.py` I would have:

```
import pytest
    
pytest_plugins = ["db_session_fixtures", "dataframe_fixtures"]
```

and I would be able to use `db_session_fixtures` and `dataframe_fixtures` seamlessly in my test cases without any additional code.

While this is handy, I feel it might hurt readability. For example, if I would not use `conftest.py` as described above, I might write in `test_a.py`

```
from .dataframe_fixtures import my_dataframe_fixture

def test_case_a(my_dataframe_fixture):
   #some tests
```

and use the fixtures as usual.

The downside is that it requires me to import the fixture, but the explicit import improves the readability of my test case, letting me know in a glance where the fixture come from, just as any other python module.

Are there downsides I am overlooking on about this solution or other advantages that `conftest.py` brings to the table, making it the best practice when setting up pytest test suites?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's not a huge amount of difference, it's mainly just down to preference. I mainly use `conftest.py` to pull in fixures that are required, but not directly used by your test. So you may have a fixture that does something useful with a database, but needs a database connection to do so. So you make the `db_connection` fixture available in `conftest.py`, and then your test only has to do something like:

`conftest.py`

```py
from tests.database_fixtures import db_connection

__all__ = ['db_connection']
```

`tests/database_fixtures.py`

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def db_connection():
    ...

@pytest.fixture
def new_user(db_connection):
    ...
```

`test/test_user.py`

```py
from tests.database_fixtures import new_user

def test_user(new_user):
    assert new_user.id > 0  # or whatever the test needs to do
```

If you didn't make `db_connection` available in `conftest.py` or directly import it then pytest would fail to find the `db_connection` fixture when trying to use the `new_user` fixture. If you directly import `db_connection` into your test file, then linters will complain that it is an unused import. Worse, some may remove it, and cause your tests to fail. So making the `db_connection` available in `conftest.py`, to me, is the simplest solution.

## Overriding Fixtures

The one significant difference is that it is easier to override fixtures using `conftest.py`. Say you have a directory layout of:

```
./
├─ conftest.py
└─ tests/
   ├─ test_foo.py
   └─ bar/
      ├─ conftest.py
      └─ test_foobar.py
```

In `conftest.py` you could have:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def some_value():
    return 'foo'
```

And then in `tests/bar/conftest.py` you could have:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def some_value(some_value):
    return some_value + 'bar'
```

Having multiple conftests allows you to override a fixture whilst still maintaining access to the original fixture. So following tests would all work.

`tests/test_foo.py`

```py
def test_foo(some_value):
    assert some_value == 'foo'
```

`tests/bar/test_foobar.py`

```py
def test_foobar(some_value):
    assert some_value == 'foobar'
```

You can still do this without `conftest.py`, but it's a bit more complicated. You'd need to do something like:

```py
import pytest

# in this scenario we would have something like:
#   mv contest.py tests/custom_fixtures.py
from tests.custom_fixtures import some_value as original_some_value

@pytest.fixture
def some_value(original_some_value):
    return original_some_value + 'bar'

def test_foobar(some_value):
    assert some_value == 'foobar'
```

Answer (score 1):

For me there is no fundamental difference, from the execution point of view the result will be the same whatever the code organization.

```bash
pytest --setup-show
# test_a.py 
#         SETUP    F f_a
#         test_a.py::test_a (fixtures used: f_a).
#         TEARDOWN F f_a
```

So it is just a matter of code organisation and it should fit the way you organise your code.

- For small code base it is perfectly Ok to define all the code in a single python file and so to use the same approach for the tests by using a single `conftest.py` file.
- For bigger code base it will become cumbersome if you do not define several modules. In my opinion it goes the same for the test and it seems perfectly fine in this case to define fixtures by module if it makes sense.

A variant that avoid importing explicitly fixtures either in the test modules or in `conftest.py` could be to stick to a convention (here assuming fixtures modules start by `fixture_` but it can be everything else) and to import it dynamically in `conftest.py`.

```py
pytest_plugins = [
    fixture.replace("/", ".").replace(".py", "")
    for fixture in glob(
        "**/fixture_*.py",
        recursive=True
    )
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The biggest disadvantage for direct import probably come from the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/how-to/fixtures.html#using-fixtures-from-other-projects) itself that mention "it is not recommended because this behavior might change/stop working in future versions."