# I am getting TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable for flask-sqlalcemy and pytest

Tags: python, flask, pytest, flask-sqlalchemy

I based some of the code on conftest.py on this post. [How do I import functions and classes into conftest.py? Or how do I import fixtures and classes into conftest.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75924656/how-do-i-import-functions-and-classes-into-conftest-py-or-how-do-i-import-fixtu)

No matter how hard I try or how I try to rename the variables I just can't find the error.
Can someone please help?

All the columns listed below are in the database and I created a pytest fixture for each.

Here is the error

```
_________________________________________________________ test_FKey_in_db2 _________________________________________________________ 

add_foreign_key = False, yield_email_form2 = <function yield_email_form2.<locals>._subfunction at 0x000002153E464CA0>
username_form = 'fkpr[kfkuh', hashed_password_form = b'$2b$12$CZtNupv1QzVm0seCRvIcOeEx52/iFfqzXJpOXI3e5TzWhX/k8Q3MO'
email_form = 'email@mail.com', item_name_form = 'donation', price_of_donation_form = 66

    def test_FKey_in_db2(add_foreign_key, yield_email_form2, username_form, hashed_password_form, email_form, item_name_form, price_of_donation_form):


>       false_output = add_foreign_key(
            yield_email_form2, username_form,
            hashed_password_form,
            email_form,
            item_name_form,
            price_of_donation_form
        )
E       TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

app\tests\test_functions.py:352: TypeError
```

Below it is not working if anyone wants to test the code.

Here is the code in config.py

```py
basedir_for_database = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
class Config(object): 

    # Setup CSRF secret key
    # change to environment variable todo!
    SECRET_KEY = 'temp_secret_key'
    # this is the test key for stripe 
    stripe.api_key = os.environ['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    # DATABASE_URI = sqlite:///app.db,  enviroment variable
    # 'sqlite:///' and os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db') = sqlite:///C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\flaskcodeusethis\flaskblog2\app\app.db
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URI') or \
    'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir_for_database, 'app.db')   
    ''' Database For pytesting'''
    # Test_DATABASE_URI = sqlite:///test_app.db.
    # 'sqlite:///' and os.path.join(basedir, 'test_app.db') = sqlite:///C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\flaskcodeusethis\flaskblog2\app\test_app.db
    Test_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('Test_DATABASE_URI') or \
    'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir_for_database, 'test_app.db')
    # for 2+ databases
    SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = { "testing_app_db": Test_DATABASE_URI }    
 
     
    DEBUG = True
    #  for pytest?
    TESTING = True
```

Here is the code in models.py

```py
app = create_app(PytestConfig)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class UserTest(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = "testing_app_db"
    __tablename__ = 'usertest'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    #  unique blocks the same usernames
    # I can't have Nullable=False because it will make me add the columns everytime I add a column in User table
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    hashed_password = db.Column(db.String(128))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    registration_confirmation_email = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False) 
    # need a better backref name.
    paymentstest = db.relationship('PaymentsTest', backref='profileinfo', lazy=True) 
    bind_key = "testing_app_db"

     
         
     
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"UserTest('{self.username}', '{self.hashed_password}', '{self.email}')" 
 


class PaymentsTest(db.Model):
    '''python
    One to many relationship
    This is the Many relationship. 
    '''
    __bind_key__ = "testing_app_db"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_name = db.Column(db.String(80)) # what value should this be
    price_of_donation = db.Column(db.Integer)
    # How do I turn email into the foreign key? todo.
    email = db.Column(db.String(120))
    usertest_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('usertest.id'))
    bind_key = "testing_app_db"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"PaymentsTest('{self.email}')"
```

Here is the code in conftest.py

```py
@pytest.fixture() 
def yield_email_form2():  
    

    '''
    Create the UserTest and the PaymentsTest db.
    Then yield the email column and finally delete the db.
    yield does not stop the code when yielded.
    '''
    
    with app.test_request_context(): # = with app.app_context() except won't work for pytest
        bind_key="testing_app_db"

        def _subfunction(username_form, hashed_password_form, email_form, item_name_form, price_of_donation_form):
            # Create the databases and the database table
            db.create_all(bind_key)
            usertest_db = UserTest(username=username_form, hashed_password=hashed_password_form, email=email_form)
            db.session.add(usertest_db)
            db.session.commit()  
            payment_db = PaymentsTest(item_name=item_name_form, price_of_donation=price_of_donation_form, email=email_form)
            db.session.add(payment_db)
            db.session.commit()
            email_form2 = 'eoafrjhfhre'
            return email_form2
        # yield unlike return doesn't stop when called.
        yield _subfunction 
        db.drop_all(bind_key)
```

Here is the code in test_functions.py

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def add_foreign_key(yield_email_form2, username_form, hashed_password_form, email_form, 
    item_name_form, price_of_donation_form):
    '''
    This runs in the /donation route.
    If the emails have the same value add the foreign key in the payment table.
    You will always have a registered account when adding Foreign key. 
    I want the foregin key to be added from the db.
    '''
    
    # Why can't parts of this be on a different line?
    email_form2 = yield_email_form2(username_form, hashed_password_form, email_form, item_name_form, price_of_donation_form)

     


    #if PaymentsTest.query.filter_by(email=email_form2).first():
    #paymentstest_db = PaymentsTest.query.filter_by(email=email_form2).first()    
    # assert paymentstest_db != None
    #else:
        # temp solution. You can't have a string of 1 string in my code
    #paymentstest_db = []


    #if UserTest.query.filter_by(email=email_form2).first():
    #usertest_db = UserTest.query.filter_by(email=email_form2).first()    
    #assert usertest_db != None, 'This has no value'


    #else:
        # temp solution. You can't have a string of 1 string in my code
    #usertest_db =[]
 
        # add the foreign key if the email exists in the User table and the email exists in the Payment table exists.
        # paymentstest_db and usertest_db makes sure the tables are not None / empty list
    if PaymentsTest.query.filter_by(email=email_form2).first() and UserTest.query.filter_by(email=email_form2).first() : 
        
        paymentstest_db = PaymentsTest.query.filter_by(email=email_form2).first()    
    
        usertest_db = UserTest.query.filter_by(email=email_form2).first()

        if usertest_db.email == paymentstest_db.email:
            # user.id is the foreign key in the Payment database. You need to manually add FK's.   
            # The foreign key "user_id = db_payment.profileinfo", is equal to the id in User table.
            usertest_db_id = paymentstest_db.profileinfo
            print(usertest_db_id)
            payments = PaymentsTest(usertest_id=usertest_db_id)
            db.session.add(payments)
            db.session.commit()
            print('Failure The Foreign key is added')
            return True
    else:
        print('Sucesss The Foreign key is not added')
        return False
    





def test_FKey_in_db2(add_foreign_key, yield_email_form2, username_form, hashed_password_form, email_form, item_name_form, price_of_donation_form):
    

    false_output = add_foreign_key(
        yield_email_form2, username_form, 
        hashed_password_form, 
        email_form, 
        item_name_form, 
        price_of_donation_form
    )

    assert false_output == False



@pytest.fixture
def False_Output_check_if_username_not_in_db(yield_usertest_db, username_form, hashed_password_form, email_form):
    '''
    if the username is not in the db the code works,
    if not it redirects.
    
    This runs in the /register route.
    username_form is in the database.
    The if statement/query will be True making,
    the output in the fixture False. 
    '''
    
    # username_form2 is equal to form.username.data/username_form outside pytest    
    usertest_db = yield_usertest_db(username_form, hashed_password_form, email_form)
    username_form = usertest_db.username 
 
    # takes into consideration if the the db is empty list []
    # In this example the if statement will succeed
    if UserTest.query.filter_by(username=username_form).first():
        print('The username' ' ' + username_form + ' ' 'is already taken. Please select another username for registration.')
        # redirects to the auth/register route in non pytest code instead of False
        return False     
    else:  
        print('The username' ' ' + username_form + ' ' 'is not taken and you can successfully register.')
        return True


# Why everytime I run the code I need to create a new test for create_db... ?
def test_registering_user2(yield_usertest_db, 
    username_form, hashed_password_form, email_form, False_Output_check_if_username_not_in_db):

    False_Output_check_if_username_not_in_db = False_Output_check_if_username_not_in_db
    (
        yield_usertest_db, 
        username_form, 
        hashed_password_form, 
        email_form
    )
    
    assert False_Output_check_if_username_not_in_db == False
```

Here is a working example where the code return False. Why is it working?

conftest.py

```py
@pytest.fixture() 
def yield_usertest_db():  
    '''
    Create the db column then yield the selected/queried usertest and finally delete the db.
    yield does not stop the code when yielded.
    '''
    
    with app.test_request_context(): # = with app.app_context() except won't work for pytest
        bind_key="testing_app_db"

        def _subfunction(username_form, hashed_password_form, email_form):
            # Create the database and the database table
            db.create_all(bind_key)
            usertest_db = UserTest(username=username_form, hashed_password=hashed_password_form, email=email_form)
            db.session.add(usertest_db)
            db.session.commit()
            # Why can't current_usertest_db be the same name as usertest_db here?
            current_usertest_db = UserTest.query.filter_by(username=username_form).first()
            return current_usertest_db
        # yield unlike return doesn't stop when called.
        yield _subfunction 
        db.drop_all(bind_key)
```

test_function.py

```py
@pytest.fixture
def False_Output_check_if_username_not_in_db(yield_usertest_db, username_form, hashed_password_form, email_form):
    '''
    if the username is not in the db the code works,
    if not it redirects.
    
    This runs in the /register route.
    username_form is in the database.
    The if statement/query will be True making,
    the output in the fixture False. 
    '''
    
    # username_form2 is equal to form.username.data/username_form outside pytest    
    usertest_db = yield_usertest_db(username_form, hashed_password_form, email_form)
    username_form = usertest_db.username 
 
    # takes into consideration if the the db is empty list []
    # In this example the if statement will succeed
    if UserTest.query.filter_by(username=username_form).first():
        print('The username' ' ' + username_form + ' ' 'is already taken. Please select another username for registration.')
        # redirects to the auth/register route in non pytest code instead of False
        return False     
    else:  
        print('The username' ' ' + username_form + ' ' 'is not taken and you can successfully register.')
        return True


# Why everytime I run the code I need to create a new test for create_db... ?
def test_registering_user2(yield_usertest_db, 
    username_form, hashed_password_form, email_form, False_Output_check_if_username_not_in_db):

    False_Output_check_if_username_not_in_db = False_Output_check_if_username_not_in_db
    (
        yield_usertest_db, 
        username_form, 
        hashed_password_form, 
        email_form
    )
    
    assert False_Output_check_if_username_not_in_db == False
```

Thanks

Comment: It's showing you the EXACT problem.  Whatever is calling `test_Fkey_in_db2` is passing `False` for the first parameter, but it absolutely must be a function.

Comment: I have a working example  that the first parameter returns False which is similar to this example

Comment: No, you don't.  The function is very clear.  The first parameter to `test_Fkey_in_db2` MUST be a function.  The only line in there CALLS that function.  It cannot be `False`.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but how do I fix the code? @TimRoberts Do I remove ```@pytest.fixture.``` I have other examples where I use a fixture then test and it works fine. Do you want to see?

Comment: I don't know who is calling `test_Fkey_in_db2`, but if you want to call the actual `add_foreign_key` function, then why do you have it as a parameter?  This could just be a simple name conflict.

Comment: @TimRoberts I added a working example that returns False where I wrote  `Here is a working example where the code return False.` Why does this example work but the other example does not?

Comment: I don't care what anything returns.  It is irrelevant.  The problem is the first parameter being passed to `test_Fkey_in_db2`.  It is `False`, and it is not allowed to be.